# The exact url for the Documents folder in my sand changes every time I run the App

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, sandbox

I found out that the exact `URL` for the `Documents` (and other subfolders of my Sandbox) changes when I run my app again. This is inconvenient as I have to rebuild the complete `NSURL` from the the file name and the current url for the documents subfolder.

Anybody knows the rationale for doing this?

Comment: This is how it works. This is how it has always worked. NEVER rely on the absolute path of the app sandbox. A user could reinstall the app. The user can update the app (which changes the path).

Comment: Thanks!. Make this an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: @rmaddy If the path to the sandbox changes when the user updates the App, wouldn't you lose the data in Documents (for example)?

Comment: No. iOS copies the old sandbox during the update (except maybe for tmp and caches).